# Sorting by * using onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, frontend

i have container called `left` for sorting and `right` for element that should be sorted.

Preview :

[image]

i'm using this code so far for `onclick` function :

```
    <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <a id="bid" onclick="sort(this.id)" href="#"><li>Bid</li></a>
      <a id="pri" onclick="sort(this.id)" href="#"><li>Price</li></a>
      <a id="alp" onclick="sort(this.id)" href="#"><li>Alphabeth</li></a>
      <a id="clo" onclick="sort(this.id)" href="#"><li>Just Closed</li></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And this the `jquery` function :

```
function sort(get) {
  if(get == 'bid') {

  } else if(get == 'pri') {

  } else if(get == 'alp') {

  } else if(get == 'clo') {

  }
}
```

**NOTE**
`bid` is for sort by bid.
`pri` is for sort by price. And others.

each container inside `right` called `product-container` . So, anyone have idea how i do it ? i have to see all of question here about this problem but got nothing. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Have a look at [isotope](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope).

Comment: @squint it was, but i delete it. And i want it filled with jquery code. :)

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks, i'll take a look :)

Comment: @TusharSharma i have read all the tutorial, but this not solved yet